# Search app in Django

Tags: python, django, search, sphinx, django-sphinx

I am building search app using django & sphinx. I got the setup working but when I search I get irrelevant results. Here is what I do -

```
# this is in my trial_data Model
search     = SphinxSearch(
                index    = 'trial_data trial_datastemmed',
                weights  = {'name': 100,},
                mode     = 'SPH_MATCH_ALL',
                rankmode = 'SPH_RANK_BM25',
                )
```

When I search I get this (from my trial data) -

```
from trial.models import *
res = trial_data.search.query('godfather')
for i in res: print i
```

> ```
> 3 Godfathers (7.000000)
> Bonanno: A Godfather's Story (1999) (6.400000)
> Disco Godfather (4.300000)
> Godfather (6.100000)
> Godfather: The Legend Continues (0.000000)
> Herschell Gordon Lewis: The Godfather of Gore (2010) (6.900000)
> Mafia: Farewell to the Godfather (0.000000)
> Mumbai Godfather (2.600000)
> Russian Godfathers (2005) (7.000000)
> Stan Tracey: The Godfather of British Jazz (2003) (6.200000)
> The Black Godfather (3.500000)
> The Burglar's Godfather (0.000000)
> The Fairy Godfather (0.000000)
> The Fairy Godfather (0.000000)
> The Godfather (9.200000)
> The Godfather (1991) (6.400000)
> ```

the problem is the most relevant result for "godfather" is shown at 19th position. All the top results are junk. How can I `order` or `sort` my results using `Django-sphinx`.

Rather, what can I do to make the results more relevant using this setup.

**NOTE:** I am using python 2.6.x + django 1.2.x + sphinx 0.99 + django-sphinx 2.3.3 + mysql

Also, the data i custom made & is only about 100 rows with only one field `name` searchable.  There is one more fields `rating` (which is what you see in brackets). `rating` field is an attribute (non searchable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can tell, there are two ways of going about this.

Firstly, there are sort modes SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE, SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC, SPH_SORT_ATTR_ASC, SPH_SORT_TIME_SEGMENTS, SPH_SORT_EXTENDED.  I assume that keyword in the SphinxSearch constructor would be `sortmode`, but I couldn't find the docs.

```
search     = SphinxSearch(
                index    = 'trial_data trial_datastemmed',
                weights  = {'name': 100,},
                mode     = 'SPH_MATCH_ALL',
                rankmode = 'SPH_RANK_BM25',
                sortmode = 'SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE', # this was added
                )
```

Secondly, you can specify at time of query the sort mode:

```
res = trial_data.search.query('godfather').order_by('@relevance')
```

Both of these answers are guesses from looking at http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/231/.  Let us know if it worked for you.

Comment: the `.order_by('@weight')` has no effect here since I am searching with only one field `name`. `@weight` makes sense if you are searching from more than one field. So coming back, I have tried this. It has no effect on the `result_set`.

Comment: @movieyoda  I edited my answer to change '@weight' to '@relevance' based on http://www.davidcramer.net/code/79/in-depth-django-sphinx-tutorial.html.